# ImagePullBackOff deploying application in OpenShift using Helm Chart

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have a Remix App which is running successfully using Docker. Then, using OpenShift and HelmChart, I'd like to deploy the application in OpenShift. However, I am getting the error **ImagePullBackOff** and not being able to pull the image:

```
oc describe pod remixapp-web-869c55d88c-djb7p
Name:                 remixapp-web-869c55d88c-djb7p
Namespace:            johndoe-dev
Priority:             -3
Priority Class Name:  sandbox-users-pods
Service Account:      default
Node:                 ip-10-0-203-61.ec2.internal/10.0.203.61
Start Time:           Thu, 07 Mar 2024 14:58:23 -0800
Labels:               app=remixapp-web
                      pod-template-hash=869c55d88c
Annotations:          k8s.ovn.org/pod-networks:
                        {"default":{"ip_addresses":["10.128.42.100/23"],"mac_address":"0a:58:0a:80:2a:64","gateway_ips":["10.128.42.1"],"routes":[{"dest":"10.128....
                      k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/network-status:
                        [{
                            "name": "ovn-kubernetes",
                            "interface": "eth0",
                            "ips": [
                                "10.128.42.100"
                            ],
                            "mac": "0a:58:0a:80:2a:64",
                            "default": true,
                            "dns": {}
                        }]
                      openshift.io/scc: restricted-v2
                      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:               Pending
SeccompProfile:       RuntimeDefault
IP:                   10.128.42.100
IPs:
  IP:           10.128.42.100
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/remixapp-web-869c55d88c
Containers:
  remixapp-web:
    Container ID:
    Image:          image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web:develop
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     250m
      memory:  512Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     150m
      memory:  512Mi
    Environment Variables from:
      remixapp-web-config  Secret  Optional: false
    Environment:           <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-wj8gl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-wj8gl:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
    ConfigMapName:           openshift-service-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From               Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       74s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned johndoe-dev/remixapp-web-869c55d88c-djb7p to ip-10-0-203-61.ec2.internal
  Normal   AddedInterface  74s                multus             Add eth0 [10.128.42.100/23] from ovn-kubernetes
  Normal   Pulling         31s (x3 over 74s)  kubelet            Pulling image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web:develop"
  Warning  Failed          31s (x3 over 74s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web:develop": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = reading manifest develop in image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web: name unknown
  Warning  Failed          31s (x3 over 74s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff         3s (x5 over 74s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web:develop"
  Warning  Failed          3s (x5 over 74s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

I created a new chart `helm create remixapp` and modified the files value.yaml and deployment.yaml with the following:

values.yaml

```yaml
app_name: remixapp
replicas: 1
image_stream_tag: develop
namespace_env: arturoreyeslopez-dev
limits_cpu: 250m
limits_memory: 512Mi
requests_cpu: 150m
requests_memory: 512Mi
cluster: silver
dockerhost: image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80
```

templates/deployment.yaml:

```yaml
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '8'
    image.openshift.io/triggers: |-
      [
        {
          "from": {
            "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
            "namespace": "{{ .Values.namespace_env }}",
            "name": "{{ .Values.app_name }}-web:{{ .Values.image_stream_tag }}"
          },
          "fieldPath": "spec.template.spec.containers[0].image"
        }
      ]
  name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace_env }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
          image: {{ .Values.dockerhost }}/{{ .Values.namespace_env }}/{{ .Values.app_name }}-web:{{ .Values.image_stream_tag }}
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: {{ .Values.limits_cpu }}
              memory: {{ .Values.limits_memory }}
            requests:
              cpu: {{ .Values.requests_cpu}}
              memory: {{ .Values.requests_memory }}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web-config
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          #volumeMounts:
          #  - name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-nginx-cache
          #    mountPath: /var/cache/nginx
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccount: default
      #volumes:
      #  - name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-nginx-cache
      #    emptyDir: {}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

templates/services.yaml:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
    name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-tcp
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-web
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Do you know why the image can not be pulled? Or any lead that I can check to figure out why this is error can occur based on my current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Post the details of how you are publishing your image.

The key bit is the `Failed to pull image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web:develop": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = reading manifest develop in image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/johndoe-dev/remixapp-web: name unknown`

That seems like the image might not have a develop tag.